# How to build object within a form in razor view

Tags: asp.net, razor, .net-core

```
public class MyModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public MyType MyType { get; set; }
    public IMyConfig MyConfig { get; set; }
}

public enum MyType 
{
    FirstConfig,
    SecondConfig,
    ThirdConfig
}

public interface IMyConfig
{
    string BuildFirstJson();
    string BuildSecondJson();
}

public class FirstConfig : IMyConfig
{
    public string cat { get; set; }
    public string dog { get; set; }
    public string lion { get; set; }

    public string BuildFirstJson()
    {
        ...
    }
    public string BuildSecondJson()
    {
        ...
    }
}

public class SecondConfig : IMyConfig
{
    public string bear { get; set; }
    public int pig { get; set; }
    public string fish { get; set; }
    public string shark { get; set; }
    public string dolphin { get; set; }

    public string BuildFirstJson()
    {
        ...
    }
    public string BuildSecondJson()
    {
        ...
    }
}

//ThirdConfig built similarly
```

So what I am trying to do is build a form in a razor view that can handle the `MyModel` class and switches the displayed `IMyConfig` bindings based on the selected `MyType` for example, if `FirstConfig` is selected from the enum list, then `FirstProp, SecondProp, ThirdProp` text boxes are displayed and when the form is submitted, those properties are correctly built into a `FirstConfig` object and passed into `MyModel` as a `IMyConfig` interface.  I have no idea how to accomplish this part, I am plan on using jquery `.change()` to listen for a switch in the `MyType` dropdown. But I am not sure how to handle the seperate displaying and automatic model building(if that makes sense).

If that doesn't make sense, the quick version is I am trying to build a razor view form for `MyModel` and don't how to approach the `MyConfig` property which is based on the `MyType` property.

```
<form asp-action="ActivityCreateSubmit">
<div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="Id" class="control-label"></label>
    <input asp-for="Id" class="form-control" />
    <span asp-validation-for="Id" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
<div class="form-group" style="display: none;">
    <label asp-for="Name" class="control-label"></label>
    <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" value="@ViewBag.AppId" />
    <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="MyType" class="control-label"></label>
    <select id="selection" asp-for="MyType" asp-items="Html.GetEnumSelectList<MyType>()">
        <option value="">Select...</option>
    </select>
    <span asp-validation-for="MyType" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
@switch(Model.MyType)
{
    case FirstConfig:
            <input name="first-input" />
            <input name="second-input" />
            <input name="third-input" />
        break;
    case SecondConfig:
           ... Do something ...
        break;
}
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
</div>
</form>
```

Controller -

```
//Ignore ActivityTable, it is a dependency injection.
public ActionResult ActivityCreateSubmit(ActivityTable at, MyModel a)
{
at.AddActivity(a)
return View("../Home/Index");
}
//This is the page I am working on creating
public ActionResult ActivityCreate()
{
    return (View());
}
```

Comment: So you want to use the same Model for different purposes?

Answer (score 0):

I could not get exactly what your problem is, but I guess you need the following (I am glad to edit the answer if that is not what you need).

you can check the selected value in that enum inside your Razor page:

```
<form>
    @switch(Model.MyType)
    {
        case FirstConfig:
                <input name="cat"/>
                <input name="dog" />
                <input name="lion" />
            break;
        case SecondConfig:
               ... Do something ...
            break;
    }
</form>
```

#### UPDATE:

The action `ActivityCreateSubmit` should have a parameter of some class type the class you require (FirstConfig). The name you gave to each input MUST be identical to the properties in your class `FirstConfig`, i.e., like this:

```
<input name="cat"/>
<input name="dog"/>
<input name="lion"/>
```

Now try to submit, it should work.

Comment: Correct, but using this method, will it build it into a `IMyConfig` object?

Comment: @asdasd2a43qaad You cannot send it back as an interface, you need to to define the implementation, i.e., you need to submit it back to the controller as a Class that implements `IMyConfig`.

Comment: Right, sorry, that's what I meant, but razor won't build that into a `FirstConfig` object and set it equal to the `MyConfig` property of `MyModel` (which is what I am returning, since my form is for the entirity of `MyModel` not just the `MyConfig` portion.

Comment: @asdasd2a43qaad, check my update, please tell me what you get.

Comment: The class `ActivityCreateSubmit` requires is `MyModel`, which has a property of `MyConfig`(the part confusing me).  The specific implemented class of `IConfig` is not known at runtime, since it changes based on what `MyType` is selected, so I can't pass that specific class into ActivityCreateSubmit.  The config portion needs to be set on the `MyConfig` object which the form is creating and passing to `ActivityCreateSubmit`.  Does that further clarify?

Comment: @asdasd2a43qaad Please edit the question to show me your controller.

Comment: If I just throw in `cat`, `dog`, `lion` properties, it has no idea to create `FirstConfig` object out of them.  How would it? since `MyModel` has a property of `IConfig`.  And `FirstConfig` implements `IConfig`.  But my razor view has no idea about what a `FirstConfig` object is.

Comment: Added my controller.

Comment: @asdasd2a43qaad, you can imagine that razor only sends a text in a special format (it really does that) when you submit the form. Your controller receives that text and using ModelBinding technology the controller creates FirstConfig object (so the controller creates the object, not razor).

Comment: Gotcha.  either way, I hardcoded dog, cat and lion, tried submitting, but the `MyConfig` property was null. (which dog, cat, and lion are suppose to create)

Comment: @asdasd2a43qaad, please show the raw HTTP of your request and response.

Comment: I couldn't find a good way to display all of the request and response, but the cat/dog/lion are correctly posted, but the `MyModel` object doesn't know what to do with it because MyModel only has a property of IConfig with properties (functions) `BuildFirstJson()` and `BuildSecondJson()`

Comment: @asdasd2a43qaad, install **Fiddler**. Using it you can view the request and response.

Comment: Okay, I mean I can if you really need it, but I promise you thats not the issue and this is a very simple example of my complex form.  It the fact that my object associated with `MyModel` is a `IConfig` and the properties that are being passed in aren't part of `IConfig` and only the implemented classes

Comment: @asdasd2a43qaad, I work the whole day with modelbinding, so it should not be problematic. Even if you installed Fiddler and I could not help you. You will be happy to use fiddler. You cannot develop web without the need of viewing your requests and responses. Fiddler (or any HTTP analyzer) is a Must-Have tool for any web developer.

Comment: @asdasd2a43qaad, so have you solved your problem? if not please post as mentioned the request and response of your form submitting.

Comment: I've decided to go with another approach because I couldn't figure this out and I am on a time crunch, I just hardcoded 10 different views and have them make an initial selection of what type they want and have different post endpoints for each.